# How to repair/replace broken 2x4 holding garage track?

Tags: garage-door

I noticed a 2x4 that my garage door track is attached to is pretty badly splitting. I figured I should replace it before it completely breaks. My question was, is it safe to just detach the track from the broken 2x4, remove the broken 2x4, install a new 2x4, and then attach the track to that new board? Or does the track need to be supported while replacing the old board?

[Pictures](https://imgur.com/a/bXQjhJa)

Comment: Who removed the washer from the bolt head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely support that track while replacing the block. Even a ratchet strap or a rope tied around a couple joists. While the track *may* stay up when the block is removed it seems as though just it's own weight might put stresses on it you do not want.

Actually a better system is to use the angle iron with holes like the adjacent garage door has. It looks like the movement and pressure of the door going up and down is what helped to split that block- the metal L-channels would not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easy enough to screw/bolt another 2x4 strut to the blocking that the existing strut is hanging off of and sandwich another 2x4 in between (effectly ending up with a triple 2x4).  Then drill a hole in one of the new 2x4s for the garage door track.

Looks like you have some cracking in the blocking too, BTW.